# Select2: Prevent Select2 dropdown from getting focused on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-select2

How can we prevent a disabled Select2 dropdown from getting focused on click. It is well prevented from getting focused on pressing 'TAB' key.

I've already tried adding tabindex='-1' to various div elements in Select2's hierarchy. None helped.

For example, refer [this link](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#disabled) to go to their documentation page and try clicking on disabled Select2 example, it will get focused, which should not happen in my case.

EDIT:

Tried @Guruprasad's answer on above mentioned link with no success on Chrome's console with following code:

```
jQuery('.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection').on('click', function () {
console.log('clicked');
jQuery('.select2-selection').blur;
});
```

'clicked' gets printed every time I click on the disabled select but it doesn't remove the focus of the element.

Comment: can you show us your html and javascript code?

Comment: @Tushar & Jeremy C - Please visit the link provided in the question above and consider the same dropdown as mine. Click on the disabled dropdown, which gets focused with blue outline. I just don't want it to get focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write this **JS**

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/k4m3p55k/)**

```
$('.select2-selection').on('click',function(){
    $(this).blur();
});
```

**UPDATE**

`blur` should be `blur()`

```
jQuery('.select2-container--disabled').on('click', function () {
    console.log('clicked');
    jQuery('.select2-selection').blur();
});
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Its very difficult for me to say that whether or not you can stop getting focused but for `ui` perspective to show user that it is disabled you can add below `css`:

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered 
{
     cursor:not-allowed;   
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/k4m3p55k/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply @Guruprasad.
Fiddle works perfectly fine. But the code didn't work for me. Even I tried it with no success on the link provided in the question on Google Chrome's console. Updating question with the code I wrote on Chrome's console.

Comment: @VibhorDube updated the answer.. Kindly check and if still the problem persists then you might need to post rendered HTML..

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: I was just wondering if we could prevent the box from getting focused. Is it possible?

Comment: _prevent the box from getting focused_. You mean not even that fraction of second blue mark on the box?

Comment: Updated the answer! Kindly go through!

Comment: _You mean not even that fraction of second blue mark on the box?_ Yes, I meant the same.
Tried your CSS code earlier as well, it didn't do the job. Please try it on the link provided in the question.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my answer the CSS code is just to give the user an impression that it is `disabled` but I doubt it is achievable as that is based on the plugin and you cannot prevent the default action from outside the `plugin`

Comment: Okay. I thought that there would be a jQuery solution to totally disable the focus. Thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: I am not sure though as I haven't mastered `jquery` totally yet.. :)